# Conditionally combine arrays of objects based on Ids

Tags: javascript

How can I add the `status` property from `object2` into `object1` based on `newEmployeeId` matching `employeeId` only if the `dependentId` is NULL.

For example: An array where Ben, Jim and Dan have statuses of Complete, Updating and Finished, respectively. Lauren should not have a status.

```
var object1 = [ 
    { name: 'Ben', employeeId: 1, dependentId: null },
    { name: 'Lauren', employeeId: 1, dependentId: 5},
    { name: 'Jim', employeeId: 2, dependentId: null },
    { name: 'Dan', employeeId: 3, dependentId: null}
];

var object2 = [ 
    { status: 'Complete', newEmployeeId: 1 },
    { status: 'Updating', newEmployeeId: 2 },
    { status: 'Finished', newEmployeeId: 3 }
];
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways you could do this; have you tried anything?  Like, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9oKN) is how you'd want to do it, but that depends on use cases not mentioned here.  Or maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7orw) instead; you said "only if the `dependentId` is NOT NULL." but given the rest of your text maybe you mean "only if the `dependentId` *is* NULL"?

Comment: You're right, I did mean is null. Thanks.

Comment: And does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7orw) meet your needs or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this.  Here's one:

```
object1.forEach(o1 => {
  if (o1.dependentId !== null) return;
  const o2 = object2.find(o2 => o2.newEmployeeId === o1.employeeId);
  if (!o2) return;
  o1.status = o2.status;
})
```

The idea is that we loop over each entry of `object1` via [the `forEach()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).  For each such entry `o1`, we first check to make sure that its `dependentId` is `null` (because you only want to operate on such entries) and give up if it isn't.

Then we search the `object2` array for a matching entry `o2` via [the `find()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).  If no such entry is found, `o2` will be `undefined` and we we give up.  Otherwise we set `o1`'s `status` property to match that of `o2`.

For the example code you gave, this produces the following final state for `object1`:

```
console.log(object1);
/* [{
  "name": "Ben",
  "employeeId": 1,
  "dependentId": null,
  "status": "Complete"
}, {
  "name": "Lauren",
  "employeeId": 1,
  "dependentId": 5
}, {
  "name": "Jim",
  "employeeId": 2,
  "dependentId": null,
  "status": "Updating"
}, {
  "name": "Dan",
  "employeeId": 3,
  "dependentId": null,
  "status": "Finished"
}]   */
```

Note that, depending on your use cases, you might want to change the implementation.  For example, if your arrays have many entries, you might want to index `object2` by `newEmployeeId` ahead of time instead of `find`ing its elements over and over again.  But that's outside the scope of the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgIzIDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYA0pyElADgDYB7AJ4QIASQAmdEAFdK6aBzISIPCCBXhJ0mXz7IAPuTkKoShmDhgZ9APx1GzEC2IBfYh4BucKMgFYcfDoMbFw8AG0AXWQAXmRwzkJyKlpkAHIAIXU0ti5eQRFxKWQ8XJU1DXUwbWM9ZFdzJIpqOjSAGTgZKGzc7n5hURrS5HL1TWrigFZ6xuSW9IApYEocvP7CmoAmMtUxqprZOobEudS0gBE4EFW+gsHigGYdivGD3X13SIBuLx8-ANwm1i8ROjCsNlaAGEBPkIJBViAIAB3ACi+QGRToBGOZCSYOs9FaAFUeBIrKwEci0et7nQgTiiBZwYT0gAxUDAegACwgEkpqPRG0e9WI3w8-lC+AAdDABFAUYguQAKAQEGIAPiInGAMGQKrwUtGlS0EmQAEIYnFDnwAJTIbrWKAgH5kBACECMPxAuISwKbGWgCQq72agT+xECmlFWKWvwG24YyQ2l3IHV6s1hu0OrrOziqqX4mzAsMFywEn6uG0eN0egR8CBSwQsFUA-DJ4gAegAVPESGQAETNCD9uj9rIgfvmfsJoUjkpTo2vCRz61Twv0Of96GwyD9ty5PvIQcpTcdLrqSecaeC+5z0pXxf7Zd0Sb7rUDoebpaUS8Dme3ukF12Y0JhXd41zLGxNxJMkwFYPcGnfI9P1HS4Jynf8ijnJ4H2ApcwL0CDmU3dkQE5HllzcaIyC7DsgA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object1.forEach(item => {
  if (!item.dependentId) {
    result = object2.find(item2 => item2.newEmployeeId === item.employeeId)
    item.status = result.status
  }
})
```